# how to images post facebook(4.x) on android

Tags: android, facebook, post, photos

How to post Facebook on android..
I can just 1 image post..
But.. I can't N images post..

show my sample code..

more..

I can't recieve error message.. 
      print logo "Sucess.." 
So, I println logo more.. 
     "response.getJSONObject(): {"data":[]}"

```
ArrayList<String> imageUrlList = new ArrayList<String>();
imageUrlList.add("https://testimage1.png");
imageUrlList.add("https://testimage2.png");
imageUrlList.add("https://testimage3.png");


Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("message", "test message");

for(int i=0 ; i<imageUrlList.size() ; i++){
     params.putString("url", info.getNewsfeed_img_url_list().get(i));
}

new GraphRequest{
     AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
     "/me/photos",
     params,
     new GraphRequest.Callback(){
          public void onComlete(GraphResponse response){
               if(response.getJSONObject() != null){
                    Log.i("YoonHS", "Sucess..");
               }else if(response.getError != null){
                    Log.i("YoonHS", "Fail..");
               }
          }
     }
  ).executeAsync();
```

Comment: Can you expand a little on this?  What happens when you try to post N images.  Do you recieve an error message, and if so what is it?

Comment: I can't recieve error message..
print logo "Sucess.."
So, I println logo more..
"response.getJSONObject(): {"data":[]}"

Comment: I think the key (url) must be difference for each value: 
params.putString("url", YourValue);

Comment: You can not upload multiple images in one go. You need to upload them separately, one after another.